# Get betas for pandas regression

Tags: python, pandas

I want to make an regression with pandas stas ols.

My relevant codeline is:

`results = pd.stats.ols.OLS(dataframe['Name'],dataframe[['IQ','Money']])`

This gives the typical multiple regression output table with regression coefficients, etc.
But I get the results with the intercept. Is there a parameter or something else for getting the betas/the standardized or normalized regression coefficients instead of the normal coefficients?

Thanks a lot!
Erik

Answer (score 0):

`results.RESULT_FIELDS` will give you a list of available outputs in Pandas, which consists of:

```
'r2',
'r2_adj',
'df',
'df_model',
'df_resid',
'rmse',
'f_stat',
'beta',
'std_err',
't_stat',
'p_value',
'nobs'
```

`results.beta` is what you are after.